# In a batch of $50$ computers numbered $1$ to $50$ , first six are defective.

Tags: combinatorics

In a batch of $50$ computers numbered $1$ to $50$ , first six are defective. find number of:

$1)$distinct sample size of $5$

$2)$sample size $5$ containing exactly $2$ defectives.

**MY WORKING:**

$1)$ The answer to first question is obviously ${50 \choose 5}=218760$

$2)$ Now such sample of size $5$ will contain $3$ undefective items and for each of those $3$ undefective it will contain $2$ defective items, i.e:

${44 \choose 3}{6 \choose 2} $

I am not quite sure about the second part. Need confirmation, and in case I have made a mistake. a bit of guidance. Thanks alot

Comment: Shouldn't it be $50-6=44$ instead of 46?

Comment: That's the typo. I am editing it. But Am I right otherwise all along?

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct.

For reference, compare to the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution).  The probability of $\dfrac{\binom{44}{3}\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{50}{5}}$ is the probability of picking exactly two defective when picking five out of these fifty where six of the fifty were defective.  The denominator is precisely the answer to the first question.  The numerator is precisely the answer to your second question.